# Get PDF (not image) file path from uri android

Tags: android, pdf, file-browser

I need to get real path of pdf file the user choosed.
Here is my code:

Button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

onActivityResult:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
String picturePath = uri.toString();
```

here is the solution for images,[Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore?newreg=eaf6649237e34289a6854c5c61abf9a2), however it does not work for pdf, because there used MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA.

Comment: Please tell what you see if you Toast or Log `uri.getPath()`. And which application was used by the intent?

Comment: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1213-181F%3ADownload%2F2%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81_4%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%9F%D0%98_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA_2014_2015.pdf

Which application?

Comment: Quite strange i must say. You did not tell which app the user used to pick the file. Can you tell what the user saw as filename while picking the file? Try other apps like ES File Explorer. You will see quite  different paths.

Comment: there are latters in russian.
2 курс_4 модуль ПИ_бак_2014_2015.pdf

Comment: O nice you are so kind to tell that. Now first try with latin filenames please. And which app was used to pick the file?

Comment: Oh, I do not know wich app was used, it is default android picker new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Comment: After that intent the user can chooce an app first. I can choose from Recent, Downloads, Documents To Go and ES File Explorer. Every app delivers the picked file different. So try all. Try ES File Explorer. I made a file with cyrillic characters in the filename and it displayes ok using ES File Explorer. Please show your code where you Toast or Log uri.getPath().

Comment: Try `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. You really see those %B4 chars? Or cyrillic?

Comment: Aha Documents to go showed these %2D's too.But it show sthe file path. So a little conversion will do i think. ES File Explorer sdelivers the file path already.

Comment: To pick file used Downloads. 
Here is the sample of toast with latin latters. content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1213-181F%3ADownload%2FResume.pdf
 
Here are code.
Uri uri = data.getData();
 String picturePath = uri.toString();
Toast.makeText(this, picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: In toast I do not see cyrillic, just %2D

Comment: Install ES File Explorer! Now did you already?

Comment: I've installed ES FE and toast text is the same.

Comment: Which one of the solutions to get the real path (from the link you posted) did you try? All?

Comment: Yes, I'v tried all. I know hot ot get the file correct name "resume.pdf" name, but I can not get the path.

Comment: So ES File Explorer delivers with uri.getPath() something that starts with content://docu... ?

Comment: what do you mean by "real path" ?

Comment: Heshan, for example real path for content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1213-181F%3ADownload%2F‌ is  /sdcard/Download/my Report.pdf

Comment: I changed the language of one of my devices to russian. ES Проводник behaved like before.

Comment: @sinitram did you get the solution, i am facing the same problem

Comment: @ParthAnjaria unfortunately, no( Then I just used images.

Comment: i need for files, can anyone help me?

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27926504/1009684